# Nested gridview show plus/minus to expand only if sub-grid has data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using this classic script to show the plus/minus icon to expand the sub grid. Because not all row in my context have data, I would like to show the plus/minus only for those row that have data in the sub grid.

this is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        });
        $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        });
    </script>
```

The method I use to load the data is the OnRowDataBound that fires a DataSet, "GetData()".

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string code = zeroLevelGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView firstLevelGrid = e.Row.FindControl("firstLevelGrid") as GridView;
        firstLevelGrid.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("thestring...", code));
        firstLevelGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

**UPDATE**
This is the html side of it:

```
<asp:GridView ID="zeroLevelGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
            DataKeyNames="Code" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBoundZeroLevel">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="35px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="firstLevelPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="firstLevelGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid" DataKeyNames="Code" OnRowDataBound="firstLevelGrid_OnRowDataBound">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="35px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                          ...................
```

How can I achieve to show the pus/minus only for rows that have a sub grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide this where you are binding the inner grid.
Make your grid image `runat=server` and where you are binding the inner gridview check number of rows in the query if it is zero hide it.

```
 var dataSource=GetData(string.Format("thestring...", code));
 //check number of rows here using count
 var count=dataSource.Count();
 if(count>0)
 {
     firstLevelGrid.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("thestring...", code));
     firstLevelGrid.DataBind();
 }
 else
 {
    //find you image and hide it
     var element = e.Row.FindControl("imageid");
    //hide it

 }
```

### Edit 1

make image `runat='server'`

```
  <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" runat="server" id="img_expand" />
```

In code behind

```
Image img=(Image)e.Row.FindControl("img_expand");
img.visisbility=fasle;
```

Comment: Thank you man. The logic you suggest is is clear. But then how do I hide it?

Comment: find image of your row and set visibility to false.

Comment: I have posted the html side of the grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.